# How much and which data annotations to use?

Tags: .net, data-annotations

I read many articles and posts about data annotations. But most of them just simple 'How to use the xxx attribute' articles. But what i did not find is any article on which annotations should be used and why or why not.

I mean, its clear that its good to use things like StringLength, Range or Required attributes and it's clear what they do. But what is with attributes like Assocation, DataType or others?
I can't think of a pratical use of them.

Which annotations do you use? How do you validate them in a windows application? I only found examples using asp validation.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Microsoft patterns & practices Enterprise Library 5.0 [Validation Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx) (VAAB) (Phew!)

There is good documentation, hands on labs and examples illustrating the benefits data annotations can bring.

Richard